# Query to bring all the data for the last day in oracle

Tags: oracle

Please advise from review perspective is that below query will fetch up all the data with context to last date or still any modification is required as i am worried from the point of last day data , i want that it should bring also all the data with context to last day

```
SELECT PFT.*, PA.* FROM PFT_DATA PFT, CONTACT_TOKEN CT, PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE PA,  PERSON P WHERE PFT.PERSON_ID = ? AND PFT.TO_CONTACT_TOKEN_ID = CT.CONTACT_TOKEN_ID  AND PFT.PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_ID = PA.PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_ID AND PFT.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID  AND PFT.CREATED_ON  between to_date('05/24/2018', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') AND  to_date('06/02/2018', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Without an insight into the data, how could anyone answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

If pft.created_on has value for the time portion of the date, then no.  Your to_date will give you 2018-06-02 00:00:00 and so a pft.created_on of 2018-06-02 00:00:01 (thru 23:59:59) would not be included.

Better to use 2018-06-02 23:59:59 as you already have the 'HH24:MI:SS' in your date mask.

And if pft.created_on happens to be a TIMESTAMP, you would be better off using TO_TIMESTAMP instead of TO_DATE.